# code, sometimes works some times doesnt. different error messages

Tags: java, internet-explorer, webdriver, webtest

i have the following issue, after perform the login, the system load the main page, its like 5 seconds doing it, so after that, the script should type over 3 fields and perform a tab to get more info, but the thing is that sometimes is working and sometimes does not, in 5 chances, only one worked, i do not know if its something about the time to get all fields or something like that, am using IE 9 cause the app only works on IE

Here´s the code:
`

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Apps\\eclipse\\IEDriverServer.ex;
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();    
driver.get("http://15.192.41.95/Cabina/asp/Login.asp");
WebElement text1 = driver.findElement(By.id("text1"));
     text1.sendKeys("xxxx");
WebElement password1 = driver.findElement(By.id("password1"));
     password1.sendKeys("xxxx");    
WebElement aceptar = driver.findElement(By.id("ok1"));
     aceptar.click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("menu")));
WebElement txtNumPolSol = driver.findElement (By.id("txtNumPolSol"));
    txtNumPolSol.sendKeys("877885");
WebElement Text8 = driver.findElement(By.name("txtNumofic"));
    Text8.sendKeys("228");          
WebElement txtCveInc = driver.findElement(By.name("txtCveInc"));
    txtCveInc.sendKeys("1");
WebElement clave = driver.findElement(By.id("txtCveInc"));
    clave.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("dest")));
WebElement txtNomrepo = driver.findElement(By.id("txtNomrepo"));
    txtNomrepo.sendKeys("Jorge Villarreal");
driver.findElement(By.id("txtRelacion")).sendKeys("Conductor");
WebElement txtTelrepo = driver.findElement(By.id("txtTelrepo"));
    txtTelrepo.sendKeys("83029090");`
```

Here the different issues i got:

1) Unable to find element with name == txtOficina

2) Element is no longer valid

3) Unable to find element with id == txtCveInc (the field is there)

4) Unable to find element with name == txtCveInc (the field is there)

The steps that the system to get the issues are:

1) Log in (so far so good)
2) The system load the main page (the page has frames and gets all fields in 5 secs...) 
3) The script type over the txtNumPolSol, txtNumofic and txtCveInc (most of the issues are in the last two fields)
4) The script performs a tab
5) The system load the some information regarding the record and the script continue...
Note: Almost all the issues occur on step 3...

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I can't see you trying to find an element with the name `txtOficina` in your test.  I can't see you trying to find an element with the name `txtCveInc` in your test.  What do you mean by element no longer valid?  If it's a StaleElemenetReferenceException adding waits is not going to do anything.  Without the markup we are going to have problems because you are obviously interacting with frames.  The most likely problem is that you are searching for elements in the wrong frame.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a timing problem. Your simulated user is proceeding faster than the page becomes ready. Depending on the timing of the page loading, different problems occur.

The solution is to add a wait after steps that trigger a DOM change than influences your next step, but doesn't cause WebDriver to wait before returning.  Google 'webdriver wait for element' to get lots of ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the similar kind of problem but i tried to find the elements with Css_Selectors and X paths instead of ids, that worked for me

Answer (score -1):

The key here is to add atleast 1 second of implicit wait after every action, i.e. send keys etc. It will allow 'driver.findElement' enough time to find the element. Though I would suggest keeping this code in a testBase or a reusable method.

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

It will help in making your webtests less flaky.

Comment: Waiting for a condition based on the change in the DOM is better than putting in timed waits. TImed waits may fail if the system is slower than 1 second for some reasons.